# JS сортировка select'a

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Можете подсказать код для сортировки select'a по алфавиту через JS. Гуглил пользовательскую сортировку в JS, но все время выдает только сортировку массива. Ума ни приложу с чего начать даже можно, примеров ноль, а сам я в JS не очень далек. Буду очень благодарен за помощь ) Может у кого то уже есть кусок кода готовый.

Comment: А откуда в select появляются несортированные данные?

Comment: Ввиду некоторых обстоятельств их на сервере нельзя отсортировать, не вижу смысла описать долго и нудно почему, ведь вопрос не в этом :)

Comment: Вопрос именно в этом. Может, Вы их в JSON получаете? А невозможность сортировки на сервере меня вообще удивляет

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var sel = document.getElementById("x");
var arr = Array.from(sel.children).sort((x, y) => {
  return x.text.localeCompare(y.text);
});
arr.forEach(x => sel.appendChild(x));
sel.selectedIndex = 0;
```

```html
<select id="x">
  <option>вафля</option>
  <option>кафель</option>
  <option>арагок</option>
  <option>турок</option>
  <option>агент007</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно работает и довольно компактно, подскажите еще дилетанту как сделать чтобы selectedIndex самый первый выбирался, а то список с середины начинается.

Comment: @D3V1L добавил.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let select = document.querySelector('select');

document.querySelector('#sortBtn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  sortIt((a, b) => a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase());
});

document.querySelector('#revertSortBtn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  sortIt((a, b) => a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b.innerHTML.toLowerCase());
});

function sortIt(comparator){
  [...select.children]
    .sort(comparator)
    .forEach(c => select.appendChild(c));
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Б</option>
  <option>А</option>
  <option>Г</option>
  <option>В</option>
</select><br /><br />
<input type='button' id='sortBtn' value="Sort it!" /> | <input type='button' id='revertSortBtn' value="Revert sort it!" />
```